# --force option frontend maven plugin

Tags: maven, npm, npm-install, frontend-maven-plugin

Is there anyway how to use `--force` option for frontend maven plugin ?

```
[INFO] --- frontend-maven-plugin:1.12.1:npm (npm install) @ justine ---
[INFO] npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
[INFO] npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should look like this :

```
                        <execution>
                            <id>npm install</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>npm</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <arguments>install --force</arguments>
                                <npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>false</npmInheritsProxyConfigFromMaven>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
```